# Filter 2D array excluding blank rows and columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Please, I need help with this. I have a 2D array or range of cells and I intend to use an excel array formula to filter this array such that all rows and columns containing entirely zero or empty cells are not included in the result.
For example, in the image below, I want to filter the given data such that the data in **Column C** and **Row 5** are removed because they contain entirely zero. Is it possible to achieve this within excel? If yes, which excel formula can I use?
**Note:** I'm using Excel 2021.

[image: 2D Array]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using MMULT:

```
=LET(
    rng,A2:F6,
    clm,COLUMNS(rng),
    f,FILTER(rng,MMULT(--(--rng=0),SEQUENCE(clm,,1,0))<>clm),
    FILTER(f,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--TRANSPOSE(f=0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(f),,1,0)))<>ROWS(f)))
```

All these should be available in Excel 2021

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works perfectly. Never in my coding life have I ever used this **MMULT** function.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
=FILTER(FILTER(A2:F6,BYROW(A2:F6,LAMBDA(a,COUNTIF(a,">0")>0))),BYCOL(A2:F6,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(c,">0")>0)))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the version of my excel doesn't support BYROW(), BYCOL() and LAMBDA() functions

Comment: @Jovanny Then I would use a helper column and a helper row using the same COUNTIF formulas.

Comment: @Jovanny please next time add the corresponding excel version tag in your question, otherwise we assume there is no excel constraints to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach which uses `CHOOSEROWS`, `CHOOSECOLS` if you have such excel functions available in your Excel version. In cell `G2`:

```
=LET(rng, A1:E5, ri, ROW(A1), ci, COLUMN(A1),
  rows, BYROW(rng, LAMBDA(a, IF(COUNTIF(a,"<>0")>0, ROW(a)-ri+1,0))),
  cols, BYCOL(rng, LAMBDA(a, IF(COUNTIF(a,"<>0")>0, COLUMN(a)-ci+1,0))),
  CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(rng, rows), cols)
)
```

or without `LET` function (shorter but more difficult to understand):

```
=CHOOSECOLS(CHOOSEROWS(A1:E5, BYROW(A1:E5, LAMBDA(a, IF(COUNTIF(a,"<>0")>0, 
  ROW(a)-ROW(A1)+1,0)))), BYCOL(A1:E5, LAMBDA(a, IF(COUNTIF(a,"<>0")>0, 
  COLUMN(a)-COLUMN(A1)+1,0))))
```

Here is the output
[image: sample excel output]

The main idea is to identify non-empty rows/columns in the range. We use `BYROW`/`BYCOL` respectively. It is important to assign `0` (non valid row or column) when the row/column is empty. `CHOOSEROWS`, `CHOOSECOLS` only take into account valid rows or columns values. Since we use `ROW/COLUMN` functions, in case the input range (`rng`) doesn't start at first row/column, we use `ri`, `ci` values to adjust it. If that is not the case it can be removed.