# Delete white cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(IF(INDEX('Matriz dependencias'!B1:BP71;MATCH(D5;'Matriz dependencias'!B1:B71;0);COLUMN('Matriz dependencias'!B1:BO71))="X";INDEX('Matriz dependencias'!B1:BP71;5;COLUMN('Matriz dependencias'!B1:BO71));""))
```

And it return an array where there are white spaces a some values that meet the condition. I have tried using `iferror`, but it does not remove cells with no value.

Any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

To filter by non-empty rows, you can use the following:

```
=LET(rng,'Matriz dependencias'!B1:BP71, n, COLUMNS(rng), 
  FILTER(rng, MMULT(--(rng=""), SEQUENCE(n,,1,0))<> n))
```

there are multiple ways of doing it. For example, you can also use `BYROW` to check row by row if all the cells of the row are empty and then `FILTER` by `BYROW` result. The above formula in my opinion is the most concise option. Credit to @ScottCraner for his approach to this similar question: [Filter 2D array excluding blank rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853110/filter-2d-array-excluding-blank-rows-and-columns).

**Note**: `MATCH` is intended for using a single column/row match, not multiple columns/rows as you have in your input. Same for `INDEX`, you can return values from a single row or column, but not a range with multiple columns.